# Bringing whale meat in to the EU

Tags: food-and-drink, eu, import-taxes, prohibited-items

Can I bring whale meat from Iceland to EU?

(I am based in Poland but I guess everywhere in the EU rules are the same.)

Comment: In Germany, importing whale meat is a criminal offence, but I *think* it is based on national law. I am not sure if there are EU wide regulations on this subject.

Comment: `guess everywhere in the EU rules are the same` No. You would get into trouble if you assume so.

Comment: @DumbCoder Well, if he assumes it's illegal everywhere and doesn't import it, he doesn't get in trouble. Whether he can get in trouble depends on if his assumption fails safe or fails deadly.

Comment: is it tasty ???

Comment: @JoeBlow it's amazing, something between pork and fish :)

Comment: "whoa" .............

Comment: Is it perfectly normal and possible to eat whale meat, in restaurants in Iceland??

Comment: @JoeBlow yes, for example [here](http://3frakkar.com/index.php?page=menus)

Comment: @JoeBlow You can find whale meat in many restaurants both in Iceland, Norway and on the Faroe Islands.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The EU has banned all imports of whale products since 1982.

Penalties can include imprisonment and large fines.

Poland [explicitly prohibits import by travellers of products of CITES species (no exceptions)](https://poland.visahq.com/customs/)

References

- [Do not bring whale meat home from Iceland](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2011/nov/02/whale-meat-iceland-british-tourists)
- [The European Union and Trade in Wild Fauna and Flora](http://ec.europa.eu/environment/cites/legislation_en.htm)
- [CITES](https://cites.org/eng/disc/how.php)

Comment: Has anyone at all been fined or imprisoned for importing whale meat to the EU or are you just quoting that to affright?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: (1) [The case has now been passed on to Berlin state prosecutors. Those in charge of the Norwegian stall could face a fine or even a prison sentence of up to five years.](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2014/jan/24/whale-meat-snacks-seized-german-trade-fair). (2) I'm quoting it to *inform*.

Comment: The case you are linking to regards commercial distribution of whale meat within Germany and not private import. In any case, these proceedings were abandonded by the German state prosecutor and it did not come to a conviction.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: Nevertheless, at least one EU government [specifically advises *tourists* that bringing whale meat into the EU may result in fines or imprisonment](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/iceland/local-laws-and-customs). More relevantly, I think we have reached a point where additional comments of this sort are unlikely to help me improve my answer.

Comment: I was not disputing that the UK government threatens with fines and imprisonment. I was asking if anyone *has been* fined or imprisoned for importing whale meat to the EU. Even the case you linked to, where whale meat was sold at a fair in Berlin, did not lead to any penal consequences.

Comment: Hmm, it would seem it is an unpunished crime.  Thanks for the info @Tor-EinarJarnbjo

Comment: @JoeBlow I found some German news reports from last year on the subject that Germans customs in Bremenhaven throughout the year had seized a whooping 4.2kg of whale salami from cruise passengers returning from Norway. The common consequence seem to be that the meat is confiscated and that the passengers get an oral warning.